# Convert MS SQL 'for xml path()' to Teradata syntax

Tags: sql-server, xml, teradata

I have a query in MS SQL:
**select convert(xml,replace((select * from Name for xml path('')),' ', ''))**
and need to convert this query in TeraData syntax.

I read that there is a procedure XMLPUBLISH in Teradata which transforms my query in XML format (like  for xml path('') in MS SQL).
But I have been unable to find an example of using this procedure.

Please, help convert the request into Teradata syntax (with this function or other).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Can you give us a simplified example of what your data looks like and your desired result?

Comment: Simple example: select * from Name for xml path('') and result <COL1>1</COL1><COL2>qwerty</COL2><COL1>2</COL1><COL2>ASDD</COL2> where COL1 and COL2 is name of columns in my table, and '1','2' and 'qwerty' 'ASDD' values in these columns, respectively